# ASP.NET GridView fire RowCommand on PageLoad

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, rowcommand

I was able to fire RowCommand and pass the needed variable to another page.

 Now what I need is to fire RowCommand after clicking a button from another page. What I think of is to reiterate back to previous page and fire another RowCommand but I need to automate it this time. Something like selectedRow++

Answer (score 0):

Use Session variable, so, increase the value of the session variable, in the second page too after desired operation.. And assign the value of the session variable where required.. :) –

Comment: Is it that you want to make the row-command event trigger automatically from the second time???

Comment: Lol..!! The thing here is rowCommand event is holding some properties like eventargs and other. Which makes use of the currently selected value from the grid view..!! So, the auto-operation doesnot makes anysense of using GridView.. :(